# Visual Studio code snippets extra line

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, code-snippets

I am using a code snippet inside Visual Studio (Community 2015) to automate the line `Debug.LogFormat("");`. The snippet is working but it adds a extra empty line (enter) at the start so using the snippet with `log`<kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> will result in the following code:

```
// blank line
Debug.LogFormat("");
```

instead of

```
Debug.LogFormat("");
```

Here is the XML of the snippet I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>Unity LogFormat</Title>
            <Author>Faas</Author>
            <Shortcut>log</Shortcut>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>  
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>Message</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Message</ToolTip>
                    <Default></Default>
                </Literal>           
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="CSharp"><![CDATA[Debug.LogFormat("$Message$");]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I can fix the problem by placing a `$end$` in the `Code` element. I don't know the root cause. Just have a try.

```
<Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[Debug.LogFormat("$Message$");$end$]]>
```

See more document about `Code` element [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171418.aspx#code).